# How do I turn an array of strings into property names on the type level?

Tags: typescript

Given the function

```
function invert(arr: string[]) {
  let result = {};

  arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    result[x] = i;
  })

  return result; // insert type cast here
}
```

What I'm basically looking for, is a way for intellisense in VSCode to tell me exactly what props are available in the resulting object, so given `const example = invert(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`

The auto-completion should show me this:
[image: Intellisense output]

My current approach involves casting the `result as {[K in T[number]]: K}` where `T` is an alias for `typeof arr`, but this approach doesn't give me any auto-completion.

What do I write to get TypeScript to do show me this stuff?

The interface `{[name]: number}` is merely a simplified example (for NDA reasons), the main question of how to map an array to property names is still the core of it all.

Comment: `invert<T extends string>(arr: T[]): Record<T, number> { ...`? Note your function isn't syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments already noted, one way to do this is to make `invert` generic. Currently `arr` is only a `string[]`. That's why your mapped type does not work.

```
function invert<T extends string>(arr: T[]): Record<T, number> {
  let result = {} as Record<T, number>;

  arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    result[x] = i;
  })

  return result
}
```

This simply generic implementation produces a `Record<T, number>` where `T` consists of the keys inside the array.

```
const example = invert(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
// const example: Record<"foo" | "bar" | "baz", number>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMA3ApgJygHgCqLoAeU6YAJgM6KVSYoDmAfABQCGmmAXIngNoBdAJQ8ASughxM5fABpEYEAFsARliaIA3gChEiADbooiTOkoh9xgLxaAvojbVxk6XIXK1mJgG5tuh5wAdMBSAKJsEAAWLCxE8jBCiFYaOnp6puaWfEQCSci+erZCfulGIJhIGRZQ2rZ+kmC0hERsSgAOhnkoGNgsfADkIXD98v0qHCOIY2wAXv3C2gD0i4gNTcStHehiElIyAERD+4gAPoj745jHZxez+-KKqupAA)

---

This works but we could still improve this a bit. As currently, the keys are only typed as `number` even though we know exactly *which* number they have.

```
function invert<T extends string[]>(arr: [...T]): { 
    [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] & string]: K extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never 
} {
  let result = {} as any;

  arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    result[x] = i;
  })

  return result
}
```

In this implementation, we map over the elements of `T` directly and filter out the number keys. Then we convert the index `K` to a number.

This results in the following return type:

```
const example = invert(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
// const example: {
//     foo: 0;
//     bar: 1;
//     baz: 2;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMA3ApgJygHgCqLoAeU6YAJgM6KVSYoDmA2gLoB8AFAIaaYBciJgDoReFgEoBAb0QAoRAsEBpZEgDW6AJ5xgiAgDJEAAwAkUgEYwGKKAF8jiLtTxMlLRIdr0wDFgJXEpBTUplIowFiIAHKEJGRUiGAgALbmWPaIAPzRiAJg6BiYcraIUvKIADboUIiY6JQgFTUAvKUlTo5gmgDcsuU8mELAcJgAolwQABYcHEQANMjiiM1speUKdQ1NTETurTC9CrbifRvVIJhIm41QsrZ9EAi0sVzJAA5Vy6qFUBxMAOTDOD-Bb-cw8EGIMFcABe-wksgA9IjEI8wM9iK8PuhpEiUYpEECBAAGXrIgmIcH8RAARjJ+MU4JhAgATPTELYgA)

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to define your array using `as const` this is a possible solution

```
type ArrayToNumberMapType<K extends string, A extends readonly K[]> = {[K in A[number]]: number}

function invert<K extends string, A extends readonly K[]>(arr: A): ArrayToNumberMapType<K, A> {
  let result: ArrayToNumberMapType<K, A> = {} as ArrayToNumberMapType<K, A>;

  arr
    .forEach(
      (x: K, i: number) => {
        result[x] = i;
      }
    )

  return result;
}

const someArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const
const mappedObject = invert(someArray)
mappedObject. // .foo, .bar or .baz
```